# How to check if a criterion is present in a range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to collect time information on a maintenance worksheet for work that was completed outside of the current work week.

Right now I am referencing each date cell individually and it works but it's a massive and clunky formula. I've tried out a number of things I haven't used before but none of them seem right. `COUNTIF` will not work because I need to sum the range based on the value in question not being present in the current range of dates.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(WT!$O$4:$O$100,WT!$C$4:$C$100,CONCATENATE("<>",$B$9),WT!$C$4:$C$100,CONCATENATE("<>",$B$10),WT!$C$4:$C$100,CONCATENATE("<>",$B$11)...
```

As I said, the output is correct but I want it to be more easily transferable and scale-able in the case of adding another worker.

Comment: The cells in question are C18:L18 on the Summary tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this in C18:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(QUERY({WT!$C4:$F100, INDIRECT("WT!"&
 ADDRESS(4,   MATCH(C7, WT!$A3:3, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(100, MATCH(C7, WT!$A3:3, 0), 4))}, 
 "select Col4 
  where Col5 is not null 
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, TEXT($B9:$B17, "yyyy-M-d"))&"'", 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow! Let me check this out

Comment: This works, thank you so much! It's gonna be some time to figure out how this works   but it works!

Comment: I don't know if you are interested but since receiving and taking apart your answer I've since completely redone my work page using query and arrays and it is faster, less complicated and clunky, and easier to use. Thank you!